ValueError: You have to specify pixel_values
Is it possible to generate an image using the CLIP model without giving a reference image? I tried to follow the documentation and came up with this:
import torch
from transformers import CLIPProcessor, CLIPModel
from PIL import Image

# Load CLIP model and processor
model = CLIPModel.from_pretrained("openai/clip-vit-base-patch32")
processor = CLIPProcessor.from_pretrained("openai/clip-vit-base-patch32")

prompts = [
    "a cat",
]

for i, prompt in enumerate(prompts):
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(prompt)
        image_features = outputs.pixel_values

    # Convert image features to image
    image = Image.fromarray(image_features[0].numpy())

    image.save(f"generated_image_{i}.png")

but I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clip.py", line 20, in <module>
    outputs = model(**inputs)
  File "/Users/x/.pyenv/versions/clip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1511, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/.pyenv/versions/clip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1520, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/.pyenv/versions/clip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/clip/modeling_clip.py", line 1110, in forward
    vision_outputs = self.vision_model(
  File "/Users/x/.pyenv/versions/clip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1511, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/.pyenv/versions/clip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1520, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/.pyenv/versions/clip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/clip/modeling_clip.py", line 847, in forward
    raise ValueError("You have to specify pixel_values")

Docs: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/en/model_doc/clip

No, that is not possible.
According to the documentation, CLIP is designed for image-text similarity and zero-shot image classification, which are tasks completely different from image generation. For any given image, the model classifies it using a list of provided prompts, which defines the classes. The image must always be used as the input.
It seems you might be looking for a different type of model architecture. There are several text-to-image model architectures available, most notably the diffusion models such as Stable Diffusion.

Are there any other major models I could use for my purpose? Apart from DAL-E and Stable Diffusion? Not looking for different variants of stable diffusion though.

or is there an image generation API/tool built specifically on top of CLIP that I could try?

Stable diffusion with its variants are current state-of-the-art for image generation. You could also look into Generative Adversarial Networks (GANs) or Variational Autoencoders (VAEs) if you want other alternatives. Why are you interested in a tool that is built on top of CLIP? CLIP is just an image encoder combined with text encoder, it doesn't have a capability to generate images.

Okay. Are there any top stable diffusion models you could recommend if one wants to try generating normal portraits (non-anime, non-animated). I want to compare results of different models
